# Disable BACS payment gateway if price is over 500

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway

I'm trying to disable the bacs gateway if the customers cart total is over £500.

I have this code here which I've placed into my storefront functions.php file

```
add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways','filter_gateways',1);
function filter_gateways($gateways){
global $woocommerce;

$min_cart_total = 500;

$cart_total = ($woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total());
$cart_total = ereg_replace("[^0-9]", "", $cart_total)/100;

if ($cart_total > $min_cart_total){
    unset($gateways['bacs']);
}

return $gateways;
}
```

But the options for bacs still shows up at the end even if my cart total is £250 for example.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your `ereg_replace` code, but I think you should for sure be using a later priority:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_available_payment_gateways','filter_gateways', 20);
function filter_gateways($gateways){

$min_cart_total = 500;

$cart_total = WC()->cart->cart_contents_total; // the total without wc_price formatting

if ($cart_total > $min_cart_total){
    unset($gateways['bacs']);
}

return $gateways;
}
```

Your code was running first, and the Woo code was probably running later and adding the gateway back to the available gateways.

Doesn't impact anything yet, but the global `$woocommerce` is deprecated in favor of `WC()`.